# How to replace global variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I was hoping someone could give me some advice on how to improve my code so that I don't need to use global variables. (I've slightly simplified/shortened the code below to focus on the problem)

The code works as follows: there are two process (pan and tilt), both of them use the function pid_process which will calculate an error number. if both pan and tilt error states are below 10 (both true), I want to do something.

I've got it working with global variables but it seems not to be the best way in Python and was wondering if someone could help me write better code.

```
tilt_error = False
pan_error = False

def checkErrorMargin(action, error):
    global tilt_error
    global pan_error

    if 'tilt' in action:
        if error < 10:      
            tilt_error = True
        else:       
            tilt_error = False
        return tilt_error
    else:
        if error < 10:          
            pan_error = True
        else:
            pan_error = False
        return pan_error


def pid_process(action, error):
    global tilt_error
    global pan_error

    # in original code - error number will be calculated here

    if 'tilt' in action:
        tilt_error = checkErrorMargin(action, error)
    else:
        pan_error = checkErrorMargin(action, error)


    if tilt_error and pan_error:
        print("do something")


for x in range(0,3):
    pid_process("pan", x+8)
    pid_process("tilt", x+1)
```

Comment: *take the values as arguments to the function*, *return values that are needed in the caller*

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure what you mean  - could you give an example?

Comment: Is it intentional that `checkErrorMargin` is going to return `True` no matter what  its arguments are?

Comment: You're already doing it with the `checkErrorMargin()` function. It's no different for `pid_process()`.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake on my side. Just updated boolean values to reflect true and false state instead of only true. good catch

Comment: `return tilt_error, pan_error`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. it's working now

```
def checkErrorMargin(action, error):

    if 'tilt' in action:
        if error < 10:      
            tilt_error = True
        else:       
            tilt_error = False
        return tilt_error
    else:
        if error < 10:          
            pan_error = True
        else:
            pan_error = False
        return pan_error


def pid_process(action, error):

    if 'tilt' in action:
        tilt_error = checkErrorMargin(action, error)
        return tilt_error
    else:
        pan_error = checkErrorMargin(action, error)
        return pan_error



for x in range(0,3):

    pan_error = pid_process("pan", x+8)
    tilt_error = pid_process("tilt", x+1)

    if tilt_error and pan_error:
        print("fire")
```